# PHP Preventing of SQL injection with OOP

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-injection

Here's a well known example how to prevent sqlinjection. There are two files like login.php and profile.php But it doesn't do anything with ether entering a correct login and pass or incorrect data. Doesn't echo about any case. SQL server goes by MAMP.
Here's the code:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "phpsec");
if ($con->connect_error){
    echo $con->connect_error;
}
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $pre_stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE email = ? AND pass = ?"); 
    $pre_stmt->bind_param("ss",$_POST["email"],$_POST["pass"]); 
    $pre_stmt->execute(); 
    $result = $pre_stmt->get_result(); 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        header("location:profile.php?email=".$row["email"]); 
    } else{
        echo "login fail";
    }
 }
?>
```

and profile.php:

```
<?phpecho "Welcome ".$_GET["email"]; ?>
```

What and where did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if `$_POST["submit"]` is set? What debugging have you done? Also don't store passwords as plaintext.

Comment: You should never ever store user passwords in plain text. You need to [hash them](http://php.net/password_hash).

Comment: `<?phpecho` <-- Notice anything funny there? Look at your page source. Guaranteed your browser is treating that as some sort of HTML tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't do anything with ether entering a correct login and pass or incorrect data"? Have you written any code for that?

Answer (score 2):

you can prevent your page from sql injection using prepared statement in php

try this code in while performing sql statements.

```
<?php
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO example(firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, 
?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

// set parameters and execute
$firstname = "parth";
$lastname = "gandhi";
$email = "gandhi@example.com";
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

here in bind_param method in first parameter s is stands for string. if you want to use integer there  you can use "i" and for decimal "d".

thanks for reading my solution.

Comment: *thanks for reading my solution.* ~ It's not a solution to the OPs question though.